# Call a function from ControllerA to ControllerB

Tags: angularjs

I've just started learning Angular.js. I'm trying to call function from CtrlA to CtrlB. How do I do that?

Here's what I have so far -

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function UserCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.users = [
        {id: 1, name: 'Mike Smith'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Jane Doe'}
    ];

    $scope.getDetails = function(userId) {
        //Call getUserById in UserDetailCtrl. How?
    };
};

function UserDetailCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.getUserById = function(userId) {
        alert('test');
    };
};
```

View -

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">
            <a ng-click="getDetails(user.id)">{{user.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zDyn2/18/

Thanks!

Comment: What do you really want getDetails to do?  Show a popup?  A good answer to your answer probably involves more than two controllers; it may involve a directive (to handle DOM events and manipulation when showing the details) and possibly a service (a singleton object that is view-independent and can be used to share data and behavior across an application).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To share data and or methods between controllers and directives use a service and inject that service where needed:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('MyDataService', function () {

    var Users = {
        activeUser: {},
        users: [{ id: 1,name: 'Mike Smith'}, 
                { id: 2,name: 'Jane Doe'}],

        setActiveUserName:function( name){
            Users.activeUser.name=name;
        }
    }

    return Users
})

function UserCtrl($scope, MyDataService) {
    $scope.users = MyDataService.users;
    $scope.setActiveUserName = function (user) {          
            MyDataService.setActiveUserName( user.name);
    }

};

function UserDetailCtrl($scope, MyDataService) {
    $scope.activeUser = MyDataService.activeUser;
};
```

DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/zDyn2/20/